# React Jest:- node:internal/process/promises:246 triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, jestjs, callback

I have below code in react.

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            await httpClient
                .get(`${config.resourceServerUrl}/inventory/`)
                .then((response) => {
                    setSponsor(response.data.sponsor);
                    setAddress(response.data.address);
                    setPhaseOfTrial(response.data.phaseOfTrial);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    alert(error);
                });
        })();
    }, []);
```

this code works successfully. only issue is , it is failing in jest test case.

```
describe('ListInventory', () => {
    it('should render successfully', () => {
        const { baseElement } = render(<ListInventory />);
        expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Below is the error.

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

I am already using `catch` block. what wrong is in the code? could you please help me with the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is below:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            let response = async () => await httpClient.get(
                `${config.resourceServerUrl}/inventory/`
            );

            response
                .then((res) => {
                    setSponsor(res.data.sponsor);
                    setAddress(res.data.address);
                    setPhaseOfTrial(res.data.phaseOfTrial);
                }).catch((error) => {
                    alert(error);
                })
        })();
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 10):

Try handling the promise using a try-catch block, as:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        let response = await httpClient.get(
          `${config.resourceServerUrl}/inventory/`
        );
        setSponsor(response.data.sponsor);
        setAddress(response.data.address);
        setPhaseOfTrial(response.data.phaseOfTrial);
      } catch(error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

or

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        let response = await httpClient.get(
          `${config.resourceServerUrl}/inventory/`
        );
        setSponsor(response.data.sponsor);
        setAddress(response.data.address);
        setPhaseOfTrial(response.data.phaseOfTrial);
    })().catch(e=>alert(e));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make your test async since you have async call in your code:

```
describe('ListInventory', () => {
    it('should render successfully', async() => {
        const { baseElement } = render(<ListInventory />);
        expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similar issue.

This issue may due to one of the object next to response.data is undefined.
Add conditions to check its presense.

This fixed my issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31701551)